# how to insert a buffer data to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to store the $newreg buffer data to mysql database. I tried with text and BLOB in mysql, but it returns error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '179' height='100' />',2)' at line 1**

Or is there any other way to do this?

```
ob_start();
echo("\n<div class='templadf_section_2'>");
echo("<img src=$tprofpic1 alt=$description />");
echo("<h4>For sale at $district</h4>");
echo("<p>$description</p>");
echo("<div class='price'>PRICE:<span> $expectedprice INR</span></div>");    
echo("<div class='readmore'><a href=$tempath>Read more</a></div>");                       
echo("</div>");
$newreg=ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: why echo? why not put this in a string?

Comment: Is there any problem using echo? I can't relate echo and mysql bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your mysql query I couldn't say for sure, but if I had to guess I would say you are not escaping the apostrophes in your query.  Make sure you are running the data through [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) prior to running your queries.

As Dagon said, you should assign the string to $newreg instead of using output buffering.  If it is spread out among the code user $newreg .= "string" to append more to the string.  Using ob works, but it adds additional overhead and depending on your code could allow for unintended text to be added to the string

Comment: I tried as Dragon said also using `mysql_rel_escape_string()`, but still having the same error. My query is `insert into entries(Entry) values('$newreg')` Using BLOB type in mysql db. There is no connection or other kinda errors, because the insertion is success when directly putting string value in the query

Comment: Whats the code you are using with mysql_real_escape_string()?  Does `mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries(Entry) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($newreg) . "')");` work?

Comment: Thanks dude, now it works fine with string. I was missing some quotes

Answer (score 0):

Other than what @CJ Wurtz's answer, I only see this solution: it seems that, You are either not using quotes for numeric value or Your input data isn't cleaned/escaped before use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newreg = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(ob_get_clean()));
```

This will escape the single quotes in your string/entry.